# Loading indicator after this.props.relay.setVariables triggered fetch?

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, graphql-js

I use `react-router-relay` and within one of my routes I have a dropdown.

Now I select a different value from that dropdown - that will call `this.props.relay.setVariables` which will fetch some data based on this variables. This data will be displayed in a chart component within the current route.

How can I provide a callback or something to know that the current component is fetching data now / finished fetching data now ?

I need this to be able to show a loading indicator on top of the chart component.

I think I can't use `react-router-relay` for this since it would only enable me to show a loading indicator instead of my current route - but I want to show the loading indicator within the current route.

Please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `setVariables` method takes a second argument, an `onReadyStateChange` callback, that can be used to detect when a request is pending and when it has completed or failed.

See also the [`setVariables` docs](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-container.html#setvariables) and the [guide to ready states](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-ready-state.html) - basically the `readyState` is an object of `{aborted, ready, done, error, ...}` which you can use to update the UI appropriately:

```
  this.props.relay.setVariables({...}, readyState => {
    if (readyState.done || readyState.aborted) {
      this.setState({loading: false});
    } else if (readyState.error) {
      this.setState({loading: false, error});
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - exactly what I was looking for.